# Batch unzip file with condition and basic file TXT read

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, 7zip

I've been playing with Batch programming lately, let me explain the whole idea, and then i'll write where i'm stucked.

I Recieve a good numeber of Zip files via FTP in **C:\Test**

I wanted to Unzip the content, which contain other Zipped files.
At this point, i want to elaborate just a subset of this files, just according to the name Containing LSP or LSG or LSP021 or LSG021

```
 [*LSP*.*,*LSG*.*,*LSP021*.*,*LSP021*.*]
```

When i find a file matching i have to

- unzip it
- open it ,reading from the 10 char on for a date,
- append the date to the name of file
- finally move it in a folder.
- (erase every temp)

Where i'am :

```
  rem loop through all the zips
for  /R "C:\Test\" %%c in (*.zip) do (`enter code here`
    rem make a temporary folder with the same name as zip to house the zip content
    if not exist %%~nc md %%~nc
    rem extract zip content into the temporary folder
    7za e -o"%%~nc" %%c
    if exist "%%~nc" (
        rem jump into the temporary folder
        pushd "%%~nc"
        if exist *.* (
            rem loop through all the files found in the temporary folder and prefix it with the zip's name
            for %%i in (*.*) do (
                ren "%%i" "%%~nc.%%i"
            )
         )
        rem jump out of the temporary folder
        popd
    )
```